# Parsing links with regex

Tags: regex, video, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a problem I can't seem to figure out how to write a regular expression correctly. How to write a regular expression that for example if I have loaded some text the part that interests me is links that end with .m3u or  m3u8. For example if i specify this input in my program

**Input** -                 `player = new Player({"player-id":"1","autoplay":"false","fullscreen":"false","debug":"true","content-volume":"85","ad-volume":"30","ad-load-timeout":"15000","div-id":"videoPlayer","default-quality-index":0,"title":"\u0428\u043f\u0438\u043e\u043d, \u043a\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0440\u044b\u0439 \u043c\u0435\u043d\u044f \u043a\u0438\u043d\u0443\u043b ","poster":"https://test/four/v1/video-file1/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/10/22/11/102211-480p.mp4/thumb-33000.jpg","content":{"mp4":[],"dash":"https://test/four/v1/video-file1/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/10/22/11/102211-,480,p.mp4.urlset/manifest.mpd","hls":"https://test/four/v1/video-file1/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/10/22/11/102211-,480,p.mp4.urlset/master.m3u8"},"about":"false","key":"4eeeb77181526bedc1025586d43a70fa","btn-play-pause":"true","btn-stop":"true","btn-fullscreen":"true","btn-prev-next":"false","btn-share":"true","btn-vk-share":"true","btn-twitter-share":"true","btn-facebook-share":"true","btn-google-share":"true","btn-linkedin-share":"true","quality":"true","volume":"true","timer":"true","timeline":"true","iframe-version":"true","max-hls-buffer-size":"10","time-from-cookie":"true","set-prerolls":["https://test/j/v.php?id=645"],"max-prerolls-impressions":1});`

By using regex the output should be -

https://test/four/v1/video-file1/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/10/22/11/102211-,480,p.mp4.urlset/master.m3u8

I have tried writing this regex expression but it parses all links and not the ones that I need. I only need the links tht end with a specific tag
Thank you for your answer in advance

Comment: Why not just parse the JSON part of your input? Then your URL is just the `.content.hls` property.

Comment: Already tried this and it did not work as i needed it to because the input contains not only json but HTML and other stuff as well. I need to solve this problem  with regex but I am unable to write an expression to parse these links correctly.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and demonstrate what you tried.

Comment: I have wrote this expression [a-z]+[:.].*?(?=\s) but it only returns links it does not check the ending tag of the link

Comment: Where is your JSON parsing code?

Comment: Forget the json dude.

^(?:[\w]\\)(\\[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.(m3u8)$ Still no luck.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex only, my solution in ASP.net would be to reverse the text first, then look up for everything between "u3m" until the next occurence of "ptth".

Regex for m3u8 OR m3u:

```
(8u3m.+?ptth)|(u3m.+?ptth)
```

ASP String reversal (from https://forums.asp.net/t/1841367.aspx?Reverse+String+in+asp+net):

```
string input = TextBox1.Text;
char[] inputarray = input.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(inputarray);
string output = new string(inputarray);
```